# Proof by Induction $\frac{n+1}{2n} = \left(1-\frac{1}{2^2}\right)\dotsc \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

proof by induction. I'm pretty close to done with this proof but got stuck at the end

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{2^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3^2}\right)\dotsc \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right) = \frac {n+1}{2n}$$

for all integers $n \geq 2$

1. basis step
   $$1-\frac{1}{2^2} = .75  \qquad \frac{2+1}{2\times2} = 3/4= .75$$
2. set $n = k$ assumed to be true
   $$\left(1-\frac{1}{2^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3^2}\right)\dotsc \left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right) = \frac {k+1}{2k}$$
3. set $n = k+1$
   $$\left(1-\frac{1}{2^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3^2}\right)\dotsc \left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right) \left(1-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right) = \frac{(k+1)+1}{2k+1}$$

from step 2 we know that

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{2^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3^2}\right)\dotsc \left(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\right) = \frac {k+1}{2k}$$

so we are going to plug that in

$$\frac {k+1}{2k} \times \left(1-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right) = \frac{(k+1)+1}{2k+1}   $$

now to get both sides equal we multiply by $2k$ to get common denominators

$$\frac{k+1}{2k} \times {\left(1-{1\over(k+1)^2}\right) \times 2k \over 2k}$$   This is the left hand side

now to combine it

$${\left((k+1) \left(1- {1\over(k+1)^2}\right) \times 2k \right)\over 2k}$$     - this is where I got stuck...

I wanted to cancel the $2k$'s on the top and bottom but then there would be no way to get it to equal the $(k+1)+1\over2(k+1)$ because the denominator required a $2k$. Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Hi, don't forget you can use MathJax to format your posts to make them more readable.

Comment: Thanks for formatting my post. I apologize for forgetting to format thanks for that!

Comment: You made a mistake in your induction step. See my answer.

Comment: It has been said that induction is a vampire: it sucks all the understanding out of a proof. Indeed, proving the identity this way gives us no idea why the result is true, as opposed to factoring $(1-\frac1{k^2})=\frac{(k-1)(k+1)}{k\cdot k}$ and then seeing what remains after we cancel everything in $$\frac{1\cdot3\cdot2\cdot4\cdots(n-1)\cdot(n+1)}{2\cdot2\cdot3\cdot3\cdots n\cdot n}.$$

Comment: But after the proof is done, it has eternal life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close.

You want to show that
$\frac {k+1}{2k} \times \left(1-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right) 
= \frac{(k+1)+1}{2k+2}
$.
Note that the denominator on the right is
$2(k+1) = 2k+2$,
not the $2k+1$ you have.
That is why you were unable
to complete the proof -
you were trying to prove
something that was false.

$\begin{array}\\
\frac {k+1}{2k} \times \left(1-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right)
&=\frac {k+1}{2k} \times \left(\frac{(k+1)^2-1}{(k+1)^2}\right)\\
&=\frac {1}{2k} \times \left(\frac{k^2+2k+1-1}{k+1}\right)\\
&=\frac {1}{2k} \times \left(\frac{k^2+2k}{k+1}\right)\\
&=\frac {1}{2k} \times \left(\frac{k(k+2)}{k+1}\right)\\
&=\frac{k+2}{2(k+1)}\\
\end{array}
$

which is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Why not multiply the whole thing by $2k\cdot (k+1)^2\cdot 2(k+1)$ and see if you get an identity (after correcting the denominator of the RHS) ...

Comment: I see that you also caught that error.

Comment: @martycohen you caught it first...

Comment: Doesn't matter - our answers were independent. That is why I upvoted you.